# Fortify Privacy Violation in ZipOutputStream.write() method

Tags: java, fortify, zipoutputstream

In Fortify code scan, we have a privacy violation in below Java code, which converts a `byte[]` to `ZipOutputStream`, which is later converted to another `byte[]`. The exact sink line is  **zos.write(arr);**

```
private byte[] zipFile(String filename, byte[] arr) throws UnableToZipException, IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
        entry.setSize(arr.length);
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(arr);
        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is it a valid violation or a false positive? I am not writing the `ZipOutputStream` to the local directory. If it is a valid privacy violation, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be looking this code in isolation. Fortify scan will also provide details on from where the data enters to this method. You need to figure out what the value getting passed to this method for `arr` parameter. If the value getting passed is private information then it will show up as privacy violation.

Comment: That array war an encrypted array. So the issue turned out to be a false positive!